# Color code Voronoi cell areas depending on number of vertices

Tags: computational-geometry, mesh

The following question is similar to [Colouring points in a Delaunay Mesh by the number of nearest neighbours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103951/colouring-points-in-a-delaunay-mesh-by-the-number-of-nearest-neighbours) ... but I do not know how adapt this answer to my problem.

I have the following image:

[image]

For detecting the white dots and displaying the Voronoi mesh without edges I use:

```
meanValues = 
  ComponentMeasurements[image,{"Centroid"}];
listData = meanValues /. Rule -> List;
listData = Partition[Flatten[listData[[All, 2]]], 2];
vm = VoronoiMesh[listData];
Graphics[{LightBlue, EdgeForm[Black], 
  MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}]}]
```

[image]

Now I would like to **display the Voronoi cell areas (overlayed with the `image` or/and together with `ListPlot` of the points `listData`**) and colorize them in such a way that different colors are used for different number of corners corresponding to a Voronoi cell (e.g. 4 corners: green, 5 corners: blue, etc. ).

How can I do that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`MeshPrimitives` returns a list of `Polygon` objects;  and it's not too tricky to  just to count the number of points in each `Polygon`:

```
colorvm = Map[{ColorData[97, First[Dimensions[First[#]]] - 2], #} &,  MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}]]]
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], colorvm}]
```

Here's what it returns on the Voronoi diagram for a bunch of random points:

[image]

The number `97` is used to access the default plot colors for MM 10, but other color schemes are available as well.

Comment: Can you please apply it to my data points ... thank you. Is it possible to overplot it with the detected positions?

Comment: I don't have time to download & import your image just now;  but if you add those two lines of code to the code you provided, it should work just fine.  If you want to add the points to the graphic, use `Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], colorvm, Point[listData]}]` as the last line instead of the one I used above.

Comment: Great ... both works

Comment: How would I use here my own color table `colTable = {Yellow, Brown, Green, LightGray, Red, Blue};` instead of `97`?. Yellow: 3 vortices, Brown: 5 vortices, etc. (see below the comment to answer from physicien)

Comment: If you want to use your own color table, replace the first line of my code with `colorvm = 
 Map[{colTable[[First[Dimensions[First[#]]] - 2]], #} &, 
  MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}]]`.  Note, though, that this will issue an error if your color table doesn't have enough entries (in your case, if any cell has more than 8 neighbors.)

Answer (score 5):

You can change the color function, but the idea is there.

```
meanValues = ComponentMeasurements[image, {"Centroid"}];
listData = meanValues /. Rule -> List;
listData = Partition[Flatten[listData[[All, 2]]], 2];
vm = VoronoiMesh[listData];

meshData = MeshPrimitives[vm, {2, "Interior"}];
iterMax = Length@meshData;
nbSideCell = Length @@@ meshData;
colorVect = Red;

Graphics[Table[{Hue[1/nbSideCell[[i]]], EdgeForm[Black], 
meshData[[i]]}, {i, iterMax}]]
```

[image: a busy cat]

Comment: Great ... so I could define my own color function and use it instead of Hue ...

Comment: Exactly! You can define it as you wish.

Comment: I used for my own `colTable = {Yellow, Brown, Green, LightGray, Red, Blue};` and then `Graphics[Table[{colTable[[nbSideCell[[i]]-2]], EdgeForm[Black], meshData[[i]]}, {i, iterMax}]]`, which works fine